# IOTA wallet not opening on W10 PC

Tags: wallet, error, windows

I Installed the newest version of the wallet from GitHub. After the installation I can see the process running in my task manager, but when I click the executable, nothing happens, the GUI doesn't show up. Can you help me out?

Comment: The newest version should be 2.5.6. Try to kill the application in the task manager and restart it. If this doesn't help reboot and reinstall, sometimes this helps (I never had any issues on W10 through)

Comment: Tried all of those things and nothing worked...any other suggestions as to what I should do? Thanks